# Why can't this integer be used as an array value?

Tags: php

I have this PHP code :

```
$qty_old = $product->getProductData (null, $product_id, null, null, 'quantity', null, '1');
$qty_old = $qty_old[0]['quantity'];
$qty_new = $qty_old - $quantity;
$product->update('product_tangible', array ('quantity' => $qty_new), 'id = "'.$product_id.'"');
```

and that produce error like this :

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array...
```

I believe the main problem is in this line :

```
$qty_new = $qty_old - $quantity;
```

it generates integer, while I read here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-scalar.php, it says

> Scalar variables are those containing an integer, float, string or
>   boolean. Types array, object and resource are not scalar.

I tried to do this :

```
$qty_new = $qty_old - $quantity;
$qty_new = (array)$qty_new;
```

but still can't get rid that error off. how to use that integer into array value? thank you

Comment: What is this $quantity?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator : it's variable taken from lines above that codes : `$quantity = $shopping_cart[$i]['quantity'];`

Comment: Right after this line `$qty_old = $qty_old[0]['quantity'];` what do you get if you `var_dump($qty_old);`?

Comment: You could try and var dump both of these variables: var_dump($qty_old) and var_dump($quantity). Maybe they are two different datatypes.

Comment: @larsAnders : I got this : `string(2) "97" string(2) "97"`

Answer (score 3):

these two lines don't make sense:

```
$qty_old = $qty_old[0]['quantity'];
$qty_new = $qty_old - $quantity;
```

**1st line:** you are giving the array the value of something that is probably not an array.

**2nd line:** you are subtracting $quantity (which might be a number) from an array, which is not an operation that is allowed on Earth :)

I recommend you change those two lines and make them do what you initially wanted them to do. If you have doubts on how to do so, explain to me what you wanted them to do and I'll include the process in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is referring to the `$qty_old = $qty_old[0]['quantity'];` line. What it's telling you is that `$qty_old` is not an array.

I'd recommend printing out `$qty_old` immediately after the call to `$product->getProductData()` to see what it gives you. This will help you understand how to use the data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the function call on line #1 is returning a single value not an array of products.

Then you try to get the first element as if it's an array, hence your error.